# How can I stop iterating once a certain number of SMS messages have been sent?

Tags: python, telebot

I'm making a telegram bot that will send SMS through a parser and I need to loop until about 20 SMS are sent.
I am using the `telebot` library to create a bot and for the parser I have `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.

```py
import telebot
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('my token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    mess = f'Привет, сегодня у меня для тебя 100 Анг слов! Удачи <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['words'])
def website(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=1)
    word = types.KeyboardButton('100 Слов')
    markup.add(word)#создание самой кнопки.
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Подевиться слова', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_user_commands(message):
    if message.text == '100 Слов':
        url = 'https://www.kreekly.com/lists/100-samyh-populyarnyh-angliyskih-slov/'
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        data = soup.find_all("div", class_="dict-word")
        for i in data:
            ENG = i.find("span", class_="eng").text
            rU = i.find("span", class_="rus").text
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ENG, parse_mode='html')
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, rU, parse_mode='html')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

I tried to do it this way:

```py
if i >= 20:
   break
```

but this does not work. I also tried to do it like this:

```py
if data.index(i) >= 20
   break
```

Comment: If you want the loop to only process the first 20 matches, use `for i in data[:20]`

Comment: better use generator - https://www.kreekly.com/random/ , 
what is the point of limiting the application to the same topic with the same words every day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with the stopping the loop or slicing the array, tell bs4 to [limit](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-limit-argument) the result:

```
data = soup.find_all("div", class_="dict-word", limit=20)
```

Comment: this does not work, i don't know why

Comment: Mmm, this should work. Please see attached link for documentation.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
for indx,i in enumerate(data):
    if index == 19: # including zero, 20th will be the 19th.
        break
    -code here-
```

`enumerate` function keeps track of current step, so at first iteration `indx = 0` , second `indx=1` and so on.

```
for indx,i in enumerate(data):
        if index < 20: # apply the code if it's under the 20th itereation.
            -code here-
```

I suggest the upper solution.

Comment: where should i paste it? '''
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        data = soup.find_all("div", class_="dict-word", limit=20)
        for i in data:
            ENG = i.find("span", class_="eng").text
            rU = i.find("span", class_="rus").text
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ENG, parse_mode='html')
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, rU, parse_mode='html')
        for index, i in enumerate (data):
            if index == 19:  # including zero, 20th will be the 19th.
                break'''

Comment: to the for i in data loop. change the loop as this